# Delete from SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void delete(String title)
{
     db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TITLE+"='"+title+"'", null);
}
```

Ive used the above code for delete in Sqlite in android

Delete does not take place.

This is the code i am using in the Activity:

```
deleteRow = deleteTitle.toString();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler = new Assignments(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            try
            {
                handler.delete(deleteRow);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            handler.close();
        }
    });
```

it goes into the try block and i get the toast of data deleted but actual delete does not take place

Comment: what do you want to delete? how did you created the thing you want to delete? ...add some code please

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String whereClause = "TITLE "+"=?";
String[]whereArgs = new String[] {title};
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause , whereArgs)
```